# How to structure my models to match my JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm just new to API and I wanted to consume third party API that was provided to me(which I don't have any control on how they structure the datas). I have asked on S.O before this post but I can't understand what or how should I do their suggestions 'Structure your classes to match your JSON Object'

My Json looks like this :

```json
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "VacationLeave": 11,
        "SickLeave": 10,
        "EmergencyLeave": 2,
        "HolidaySwap": 1,
        "OldLeave": 1
    }
}
```

And on my controllers I have this

```
public IActionResult APICall() 
{
    // Fetch the JSON string from URL.
    List<APIResponse> leaves = new List<APIResponse>();
    string apiUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxx.xxx/GetLeaveBalance/2170";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        leaves = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIResponse>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }

    // Return the Deserialized JSON object.
    return Json(leaves);
}
```

My model classes :

```
public class APIResponse : LeaveModel
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<LeaveModel> Leaves;
}

public class LeaveModel
{
    public int VacationLeave { get; set; }
    public int SickLeave { get; set; }
    public int EmergencyLeave { get; set; }
    public int HolidaySwap { get; set; }
    public int OldSwap { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is: I get this error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APITest.Models.APIResponse]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Can anyone help me what I'm missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `APIResponse` should support generic.

```cs
public class APIResponse<T>
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

As the `data` is a `LeaveModel` object but not a `LeaveModel` array.

And deserialize as `APIResponse<LeaveModel>` type.

```cs
APIResponse<LeaveModel> apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse<LeaveModel>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
LeaveModel leave = apiResponse.Data;
```

And would suggest changing the method to asynchronous.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> APICallAsync() 
{
    //Fetch the JSON string from URL.
    LeaveModel leave = new LeaveModel();
    string apiUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxx.xxx/GetLeaveBalance/2170";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        APIResponse<LeaveModel> apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse<LeaveModel>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());  
        leave = apiResponse.Data;        
    }

    //Return the Deserialized JSON object.
    return Json(leave);
}
```

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyvxy.png) I'm having this error on Intellisense and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<APITest.Models.LeaveModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<APITest.Models.APIResponse>' APITest `

Comment: No, you can't do like that. As modified the `APIResponse` support the generic type. You should provide the type to APIResponse. For example: `List<APIResponse<LeaveModel>>`.

Comment: Also you may check my latest answer, this would be the expected code to fix the issue. I don't see the reason you deserialize as `List<LeaveModel>` or `List<APIResponse<LeaveModel>>`, as your JSON data is `APIResponse<LeaveModel>` type.

Comment: thank you. I'm new to this Async,Task how can I invoke /call this `public async Task<IActionResult> APICallAsync()` your code above and intellisense suggest to add Task Type

Comment: Oops, yes, as the method is changed to asynchronous type. The return type should be `Task<IActionResult>`. And to call this method from somewhere, `await APICallAsync();`. Think this [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) is good for you to understand the asynchronous programming.

Comment: one last thing how can I add parameter ? I did this but it doesn't work: `public async Task<IActionResult>LeaveBalanceAsync(int empnum)
        {


            return await APICallAsync(empnum);

            

        }`  also added  ` public async Task<IActionResult> APICallAsync(int emp)
        {
            //Fetch the JSON string from URL.
            LeaveModel leave = new LeaveModel();
            string apiUrl = $"http://xxx.xxx.xxx/GetLeaveBalance/{emp}"; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244172/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-john-phillip-abello).

Answer (score 0):

As per json ApiResponse class must look like this

```
 public class APIResponse : LeaveModel
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public LeaveModel data;
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error